# Timing Json in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to achieve a simple TextDisplay. The example is better explained by the following code:

```
var poem = {
    en: {
        l1 : "Take this kiss upon the brow!",
        l2 : "And, in parting from you now,",
        l3 : "Thus much let me avow",
        l4 : "You are not wrong, who deem",
        l5 : "That my days have been a dream;",
        l6 : "Yet if hope has flown away",
        l7 : "In a night, or in a day,",
        l8 : "In a vision, or in none,",
        l9 : "Is it therefore the less gone?",
        l10: "All that we see or seem",
        l11: "Is but a dream within a dream."
    },
    it: { 
        l1 : "Questo mio bacio accogli sulla fronte!",
        l2 : "E, da te ora separandomi,",
        l3 : "lascia che io ti dica",
        l4 : "che non sbagli se pensi",
        l5 : "che furono un sogno i miei giorni;",
        l6 : "e, tuttavia, se la speranza volò via",
        l7 : "in una notte o in un giorno,",
        l8 : "in una visione o in nient'altro,",
        l9 : "e' forse per questo meno svanita?",
        l10: "Tutto quello che vediamo, quel che sembriamo",
        l11: "non è che un sogno dentro un sogno." 
    }
},
jsonTime = {
    t1 : 3000,
    t2 : 3250,
    t3 : 2985,
    t4 : 3125,
    t5 : 3625,
    t6 : 3100,
    t7 : 3400,
    t8 : 2843,
    t9 : 3123,
    t10: 2964,
    t11: 3150
};


function sayPoem(poem, lang){

};
```

As you can see I got one object for poem containing serveral languages of the same poem, and a second object to who containg the lifespam in milliseconds of every line of the poem.

Got any idea on how can I achieve this result ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Warning: using `setTimeout` will drift in relation to the movie. You will need a sync mechanism

Comment: also your work would probably be easier if you had an array of verses like `[{en:"english verse", it:"italian verse", time: 3000}, ...]`

Comment: @BenAston, I don't think this is related to video ("subtitle" is being used incorrectly). "text display" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the advice. I edit the question.

Comment: _how can I achieve this result_ which result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some arrays from the object keys (makes iterating through the lines easier), and use `setTimeout` to display the text.

```
function sayPoem(poem, jsonTime, lang) {
    var count = 0;
    var obj = poem[lang];
    var poemKeyArr = Object.keys(obj);
    var timeKeyArr = Object.keys(jsonTime);
    var div = document.getElementById('poem');
    var line, time, timer;
    var showText = function showText() {
        if (count < poemKeyArr.length) {
            line = poemKeyArr[count];
            time = timeKeyArr[count++];
            div.textContent = obj[line];
            timer = setTimeout(showText, jsonTime[time]);
        } else {
          clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    }
    showText();
}

sayPoem(poem, jsonTime, 'en');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uonhpgo4/11/)